# Punishment for brahmana for hearing?

Tags: scripture, brahmins, punishment

I have seen that scriptures tell a shudra should not hear. when shudra hear then others should keep Lead/oil on ears. But I did not see that one scripture did not told brahmin should not hear. when brahmin hears keep lead/oil on their ear. Does any scripture tell as such?

Comment: hear what exactly?

Comment: It is mandated that molten lead be poured in the ears of a Shudra in case of him hearing Vaidika mantras, not for eavesdropping.

Comment: should not hear what ? Yajurveda 26.2 clearly says that vedas can be heard by anyone

Comment: I did not kept tag of Veda . I did not kept Dayanand Saraswati bhashya